# pythonのinput()のする回数がわからないときの解決策について

Tags: python

atcoderの問題を解く際、標準入力の個数がわからないことがあり、そのような場合にどうやってpythonで記述すればいいのか教えて下さい。この質問が不適切なら、教えてください。
[atcoder abc 147 c](https://atcoder.jp/contests/abc147/tasks/abc147_c)

Comment: この辺の記事が参考になるのでは？[atcoderでよく使う手法python版](https://qiita.com/chun1182/items/ddf2b6cba932b2bb0d4e), [Pythonで使う競技プログラミング用チートシート](https://qiita.com/_-_-_-_-_/items/34f933adc7be875e61d0), [PythonでAtCoder青になるまで -Pythonで競プロやるときに気をつけること-](https://qiita.com/Kentaro_okumura/items/a6917572756a2e3c0da9), [Pythonで競プロやるときによく書くコードをまとめてみた](https://qiita.com/y-tsutsu/items/aa7e8e809d6ac167d6a1)

Answer (score 1):

## 質問に対する回答

本家SOより引用：

> [`file.read`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes#file.read) を使いましょう。
>
> `input_str = sys.stdin.read()`
> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21235855/how-to-read-user-input-until-eof/36237166

入力用のファイルを作り、リダイレクトで渡しながら動作を確認するとよいでしょう。

## 質問で示されたAtCoderの問題に対しての回答

AtCoderを含め、多くのプログラミングコンテストでは入力の行数は判別可能です。以下に例を示します。

1. 最初の入力で、 `N` が2だとするとAの添字はA_1及びA_2が入力されます。
2. A_1 が3だとすると、3行に渡って次のような入力が行われます。

> x_{11} y_{11}
> x_{12} y_{12}
> x_{13} y_{13}

3. 次にA_2が2だとすると、2行に渡って入力が行われます。

> x_{21} y_{21}
> x_{22} y_{22}

以上で入力は終了します。最後の `x_{22} y_{22}` が `x_{NA_{N}} y_{NA_{N}}` に相当するのがわかるでしょうか。